# SchemaRegistryClient cache not working, unnecessary Schemaregistry GET requests are the problem,

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, apache-nifi, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Kafka to deserialize Avro messages. For that the programm should pull the corresponding Schema from the Schema registry.
The streaming app is implemented as a Nifi processor, which works in itself. The problem is, that after every flow, a new Schema is being requested. No Schema seems to be cached.

This part of the log here is the problem:

```
    2019-04-16 22:08:51,333 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2]                 i.c.k.s.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values:
        schema.registry.url = [http://localhost:8081]
        max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
        specific.avro.reader = false
```

When calling a CachedSchemaRegistryClient, one would think that the schemas are being cached automatically?

```
private SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient;

            this.schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaUrl, 1000);
```

So when a Schema is needed, a call with the following

```
return schemaRegistryClientProvider.getSchemaRegistryClient().getByID(avroSchemaId);
```

Is supplying it. But each time we are making a new GET request.

Else the processor is working as intended. Just all those extra calls to the Schemaregistry are a huge burden over time.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

EDIT:

The Cache is working as intended. It was was just a initialization problem that caused it to re-load the schema URL at every onTrigger().

Comment: Did you write that processor? NiFi has its own implementation of the Schema registry client.

Comment: No i did not. But I need to debug it. Either the implementation does not include a cache or I am using it wrong/not at all.

Comment: Last time I looked at the Nifi code, it does regularly poll all the subject names. I'm not sure about the get by id function

Answer (score 0):

The code for retrieving the schema does not seem correct.

The SchemaRegistryClient interface only has two methods:

```
RecordSchema getSchema(String schemaName) throws IOException, SchemaNotFoundException;

RecordSchema getSchema(int schemaId) throws IOException, SchemaNotFoundException;
```

I'm not sure where the getByID method is coming from, but I think you are somehow bypassing the caching by going through a different code path.